# C# populating a column chart with data from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, charts

I'm trying to build a column chart that takes it's data from an array of numbers. Essentially, I have several groups of objects that have a property called Cost. The chart needs to be able to display the spread of the costs of these objects. Since all of the costs are integer based I figured I could place the counts of each cost in an array starting from the lowest cost and going to the highest.
I have tried assigning the chart's Data source to my array but it doesn't show anything other than the little marker that says Series 1. Please help.

EDIT:
I have really only tried `CostChart.DataSource = values //values is the array that has the counts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] arr = new int[]{ 10, 1,2,3,4,5};

Array.Sort(arr);

chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(arr);
```

EDIT:

You can add this code to change the labels on your X-axis(labels below) to your desired label instead of its default numbering labels.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0.5, 1.5, "test");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1.5, 2.5, "test2");
```

Comment: ok that gets it to display but now the labels on the x-axis are all shifted by 1... (e.g. free items are now costing 1, all increasing the cost by 1)

Comment: what I ended up doing was I just changed to use DataBindXY and passed it 2 arrays instead of one like so `chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, values);`